# MySQL stored proc not getting created

Tags: mysql

So I have this stored proc that will not get created when I run the file.

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS msd.test_proc//
CREATE PROCEDURE msd.test_proc()
    BEGIN

        SELECT 
            'Hello proc'
        FROM 
            msd.zipcode_lookup;

    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this I get an error code 1064 at line 1 when I execute in RazorSQL. Here is the complete error message:

```
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '//
CREATE PROCEDURE msd.test_proc()
BEGIN

    SELECT

        'Hello proc'
    FROM ' at line 1
Error Code:1064
```

I've tried other variations and still get errors. I am sure this is something basic I am missing. I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message, in full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated on the [RazorSQL website](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/support_mysql_delimiter.html):

> The DELIMITER statement is not part of the MySQL language. It is a command supported by certain MySQL tools. This command tells those MySQL programs to scan for a certain character that indicates the end of a query or statement.
>
> RazorSQL does not support using the DELIMITER command. The SQL statement delimiter value used by RazorSQL can be changed using the preferences window. The default values is the semi-colon.